# Web: Textbox value attribute not the same as value in textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textbox

I am using Visual Studio 2010 updated to the latest version and the MVC3 framework updated to the latest version.  I am also using jquery 1.5.1 but this issue does not appear to be jquery related.

I have the following main page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"  type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/UserMaintainance.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/UserMaintainance.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@model TourSystem2.Models.UserMaintainanceViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserMaintainance";
}

@Model.Debug

<h2>User Maintainance</h2>
<div id = "EditUser"></div>
<table>
<tr id="1">
    <td><button type="button"  class = "deleteButton"></button></td>

    <td><button type="button"  class = "editButton"></button></td>
    <td>John                          </td>
    <td>john                          </td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1234                </td>
    <td></td>

    //snipped some unrelated form generation of user information showing
    <tr id = "0">
    <td colspan = "7"><button type = "button" id = "addButton">Add New User</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the java script for this form, I do the following for the addButton:

```
$(function () {
$(':button.editButton, :button#addButton').click(function () {
    var myData = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    $.post("/Admin/EditUser", { UserID: myData },
        function (data) {
            $('#EditUser').html(data);
            $('#EditUser').dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 400,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });


        });  //end post
});
```

The partial page /Admin/EditUser looks like this:

```
@model TourSystem2.Models.UserEditViewModel
<link href="/Content/UserEdit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.UserInfo.iUserID)      
<table id="useredit">
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.UserInfo.cLoginName, "Login Name")</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.UserInfo.cLoginName)</td>
    </tr>
    //Snip more fields
</table>
```

My controller code for EditUser looks like:

```
    public ActionResult EditUser(int UserID)
    {
        UserEditViewModel myUser = new UserEditViewModel();

        if (UserID == 0)
        {
            myUser.UserInfo.iUserID = 0;
            return PartialView("UserEdit", myUser);
        }
        else if (myUser.Load(UserID))
        {
            return PartialView("UserEdit", myUser);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("Broken: " + myUser.Debug);
        }
    }
```

My intention is that upon clicking save, I will do another AJAX post to pass the information back to the server.

So far, everything is working pretty well except the value attribute of the textbox does not change even though the text in the box has changed.  If I click on edit, the data files out correctly on the editUser partial page... but any changes are not reflected in the value.

Using firebug, I can visually see that value does not change for any textbox I have on the screen.  During the "save user" post, only the original value is returned and not the modified value.

Did I miss something very basic?

*EDIT 1***
I am trying to do the following in my SaveButton event:

```
                    "Save": function () {
                        var myUser =
                            {
                                iUserID: ('#UserInfo_iUserID').val,
                                cLoginName: ('#UserInfo_cLoginName').val,
                            };
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/admin/SaveUser",
                                data: myUser,
                                success: function (bNum) {
                                    alert("returned" + bNum);
                                }
                            });
```

I am getting old results for the cLoginName: ('#UserInfo_cLoginName').val

This happens before the second POST.

Comment: Added edit 1... still learning system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a common gotcha when you try to modify values in a POST action that are contained in the `ModelState` and rendering the same view. You will need to remove the value from model state before changing it or HTML helpers (such as `HiddenFor`) will use the POSTed value when binding:

```
ModelState.Remove("UserInfo.iUserID");
myUser.UserInfo.iUserID = 0;
return PartialView("UserEdit", myUser);
```

Verify by debugging that ModelState contains a value called `UserInfo.iUserID`.

---

UPDATE:

It seems that the wrong syntax is used to retrieve the values:

```
('#UserInfo_iUserID').val
```

instead of:

```
$('#UserInfo_iUserID').val()
```

Comment: As mentioned in another reply, my issue is I can't get the value the user entered into the textbox using                                 cLoginName: ('#UserInfo_cLoginName').val,
Thus, it doesn't even come to the controller with the correct value to begin with.

Comment: @John Stone, `val` is a function not a property. You also miss a `$` at the beginning. So the correct syntax should be like this: `$('#UserInfo_iUserID').val()` and not `('#UserInfo_cLoginName').val`.

Comment: thank you... that was the issue.  *embarrassed*  Coding with little sleep or coffee is bad news.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as Darrin described below
See [Updating value provider prior to TryUpdateModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544663/updating-value-provider-prior-to-tryupdatemodel/3673915#3673915)
The helpers exhibit this behavior because they assume if you are redisplaying data after a post there should be a validation failure otherwise you would be redirecting to a get action as part of the MVC PRG (post redirect get)pattern

I believe your issue though is different as was pointed out below.

Comment: The problem is when I use cLoginName: ('#UserInfo_cLoginName').val before I post, I do not get the correct value that the user entered.  Thus I can't even post the right value to begin with.  What I am trying to do fails completely before it even gets to the controller.  Which begs how do I get the users input and not the outdated value?