# TextBoxFor Helper retains previous value even when model value is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC form for adding a simple entity.  I am using TextBoxFor(model => model.FieldName) to create the input fields.  I have a Save button and a Save and New button.  The Save and New button is supposed to post back to the Save action and then return the current View with an empty model to enable the user to add another entity.  However, what happens is that, even though the model is indeed empty, the input fields are being generated with the values entered for the previous entity.  Hope this makes sense.

I know I could do a redirect, but that seems like an ugly workaround, so if anyone has run into this before, I'd really appreciate some input.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?  Ideally from the action.

Comment: Not sure you should be POSTing for the New button action. That action should be a GET request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue here is that your `ViewData.ModelState` is still populated with the values from the original post, even if the `Model` is null and you don't explicitly pass any values into your view.

I actually don't think redirecting to the original action is that ugly of a solution, but if you don't want to do that then clearing out the `ViewData` should work for you:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(TestModel model)
{            
    ViewData = null;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

instead of

```
ViewData = null;
```

since I find that much more clear what you are trying to do. Although both will accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue see here:

[Updating value provider prior to TryUpdateModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544663/updating-value-provider-prior-to-tryupdatemodel/3673915#3673915)

However - after a post - if it is successful, you should *by design* be redirecting to a GET action for your next data. This is part of the PRG (post-redirect-get) pattern that is meant to be used by mvc. The helpers assume you are using this pattern and if you are displaying information after a post, there mustve been an error so they redisplay the posted values for "correcting". Try not to work around this - but refactor your code to properly work with PRG.

Comment: Isn't this inefficient?  Doesn't a redirect cause an extra round-trip from the client to server and back?  Or is that not the case with RedirectToAction?

Comment: Define 'inefficient'? Its the way it was designed to work and is much cleaner. Many web forms applications suffer from showing data on postback that doesn't properly reflect how it looks if you load the data fresh again. MVC solves this by redirecting back to your get. Its much cleaner, and the client also can press f5 without the dreaded warning message from the browser that clients have no idea about.